# What seems wrong with this bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, redhat, shell

I found an initscript that for some reason insists on starting the specified application as the root user. I can't wrap my head around why it is doing this, any hints? The script runs on Redhat Enterprise Linux 5.9.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Start/Stop apfe.
#
# chkconfig: - 62 38
# description: apfe   
# Start script for an apfe process.
# Apfe does not normally run as root, so we change user
# and call the real script in $USERDIR.

STARTUSER=apfe
USERDIR=/app/apfe/apps/apfeutils/bin
PROGNAME=apfe

su - $STARTUSER -c "$USERDIR/$PROGNAME $*"
```

Comment: From what I can see it starts the `apfe` executable as `apfe`, not `root`

Comment: Exactly, that's what I see too. But even so it starts and runs at root upon e.g a reboot of the system.

Comment: Are you sure there's nothing funky about the script $USERDIR/$PROGNAME? Try replacing the `"$USERDIR/$ROGNAME $*"` part with `whoami >> /tmp/apfeuser.$$` (`id -un >> /tmp/apfeuser.$$`) to store the effective user ID the script runs as. If that's $STARTUSER, it's the called script itself that does something to alter the security context further.

Comment: Sorry guys, it was I who was looking at the wrong process.. this script does indeed start the application as the user apfe. Sorry for wasting your time!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because PEBKAC ;)

Answer (score 1):

Note that `su -` means command has to start in user login shell loading user environment too. In case that login shell is something like `/bin/false` for security reasons, there should be a problem.

Try to change `su` to `sudo -u $STARTUSER ...` and potentially do fine settings in `/etc/sudoers` for that command.

Comment: I still think it's much better to use `-m` switch then bringing sudo here.

Answer (score 0):

I see a potential problem in that there's no full path to the `su` binary, and no guarantee you have a $PATH at all. My preferred solution would be to use `runuser` as opposed to `su` (see the `postgresql` startup file and `man runuser` for details) after sourcing the `/etc/init.d/functions` file, another solution would be to use the full path to the `su` binary. There may be other solutions available as well. Of course, this may not be the issue you're facing, but it answers your question of "What seems wrong". :)

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/542603/what-seems-wrong-with-this-bash-script#comment624962_542603